# UWP Coutinuous Speech Recognition Wildcards

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, speech

I am working with Windows Universal Application and need to make a voice command that takes the users sentence and fills in the fields on screen. Examples of these fields include Name and date of birth. I cannot use the  in an SRGS file because I do not know all the names and adding all possible names would not work. Is there a way to indicate where a wild card value will show up and then later grab that value from the command? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Predefined grammars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-interactions#constraints), AKA topic constraint as the constraint of [SpeechRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.aspx).

You can specify the scenario of `SpeechRecognition` and `TopicHint` like this:

```
var dictationConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.FormFilling, "Person Name");
```

And together add your SRGS file as constraint and this topic constraint into the `SpeechRecognizer`:

```
var dictationConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.FormFilling, "Person Name");
var grammarfileConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(sgrsFile);
speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(dictationConstraint);
speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarfileConstraint);
```

Although it can not ensure 100% correctly get your voice input due to accent, noise or other possible disturbances, but it will automatically try its best to convert your voice input to the topic of "Person Name".

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have question. For example, if I have the sentence "Search John Smith". Would I be able to use the key "Person Name" to return the name "John Smith"?

Comment: @NotMike, yes it's possible, you can catch the voice input and match the name to your local database or list of name, it's about how to deal with the result of your speech recognizer. Is my answer a acceptable answer?